# Regex to check if first 2 characters in a string are Alphabets

Tags: regex, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm new to actionscript and i cant seem to get the regex syntax right in actionscript3. The task is straight forward, i want to make sure that the first two characters in a given string are alphabets and nothing else. Here's what I'm doing and obviously it doesn't work or i wouldn't be here! ;-).

what am I doing wrong here?

```
var fileName:String = "- Earth"; 
var pattern:RegExp = /(A-Z)(a-z){0,1}/;
if (pattern.test(fileName)) {
   Alert.show("Trew");    
}
else {
   Alert.show("phalse");
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Not familiar with actionscript, but if it follows normal regex type rules, you need a regex more like:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{2}/
```

to match two alpha characters at the start of a string.

Comment: How can we negate this same expression? I want to negative condition for initial 2 letters. I tried /(?!(^[A-Za-z]{2}))/ which is not working